# Microsoft Virtual Assistant Template deploy failure

Tags: botframework

I'm attempting to deploy the Microsoft's botframework Virtual Assistant Template solution, but am getting a number of errors thrown when the deploy.ps1 PowerShell script is run. As the script output below shows, the errors stem from additional PowerShell scripts called by the deploy.ps1 script. Anyone seen this before and deal with it successfully?

PS C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1> .\deployment\scripts\deploy.ps1
? Bot Name (used as default name for resource group and deployed resources): stuartbottest1
? Azure resource group region: eastus2
? Password for MSA app registration (must be at least 16 characters long, contain at least 1 special character, and contain at least 1 numeric character): Chicrbwisf@stuartbottest1
? LUIS Authoring Region (westus, westeurope, or australiaeast): westus
? LUIS Authoring Key (found at https://luis.ai/user/settings): lasdfljwrlkkjxoiuc

> Creating resource group ...
>   Validating Azure deployment ...
>   Deploying Azure services (this could take a while)...
>   Updating appsettings.json ...
>   Deploying cognitive models ...
>   Initializing dispatch model ...
>   dispatch : The term 'dispatch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\deploy_cognitive_models.ps1:125 char:4
>   +         (dispatch init 
>   `+          ~~~~~~~~                                                                                                     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dispatch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                              > Parsing General LU file ...
>   ludown : The term 'ludown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\luis_functions.ps1:10 char:5
>   +     ludown parse toluis`
>   +     ~~~~~~                                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ludown:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                              > Deploying General LUIS app ...
>   luis : The term 'luis' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\luis_functions.ps1:18 char:17
>   +     $luisApp = (luis import application 
>   `+                 ~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (luis:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                              ! Could not deploy LUIS model. Review the log for more information.                                                     ! Log: C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
>   Setting LUIS subscription key ...
>   ! Could not create LUIS app. Skipping dispatch add.
>   Parsing Chitchat LU file ...
>   ludown : The term 'ludown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:9 char:5                                +     ludown parse toqna`                                                                                              +     ~~~~~~                                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ludown:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Deploying Chitchat QnA kb ...
>   qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb `+                   ~~~~~~~~                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
>   2
>   Retrying ...
>   qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb`
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>                                                                                                                           1                                                                                                                       > Retrying ...                                                                                                          qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb 
>   `+                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                              0                                                                                                                       > Retrying ...                                                                                                          qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb`
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                              -1                                                                                                                      ! Unable to create QnA KB.                                                                                              ! Could not deploy knowledgebase. Review the log for more information.
>   ! Log: C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
>   ! Could not create knowledgebase. Skipping dispatch add.
>   Parsing Faq LU file ...
>   ludown : The term 'ludown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:9 char:5                                +     ludown parse toqna `                                                                                              +     ~~~~~~                                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ludown:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Deploying Faq QnA kb ...
>   qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb `+                   ~~~~~~~~                                                                                            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
>   2
>   Retrying ...
>   qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb`
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>                                                                                                                           1                                                                                                                       > Retrying ...                                                                                                          qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb 
>   `+                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>                                                                                                                           0                                                                                                                       > Retrying ...                                                                                                          qnamaker : The term 'qnamaker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.               At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\qna_functions.ps1:24 char:13
>   +         $qnaKb = (qnamaker create kb`
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qnamaker:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-1
! Unable to create QnA KB.
! Could not deploy knowledgebase. Review the log for more information.
! Log: C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
! Could not create knowledgebase. Skipping dispatch add.

> Creating dispatch model...
>   dispatch : The term 'dispatch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts\deploy_cognitive_models.ps1:251 char:16
>   +         $dispatch = (dispatch create `
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dispatch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

! Could not create Dispatch app. Review the log for more information.
! Log: C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1\deployment\scripts..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt

> Publishing to Azure ...
>   Done.
>   PS C:\source\repos\stuartbottest1\stuartbottest1>

Comment: Here's a link to the solution: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/docs#tutorials

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md#download-and-install)? According to your log, you are missing a few CLI tools. `npm install -g botdispatch ludown luis-apis qnamaker luisgen@2.0.2`

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks for the response. Yes, I ran through all the prereq installations, including the botdispatch install. It did throw a warning about hoek@5.0.4 being deprecated, but was otherwise successful.

Comment: So having gone through the installation process several times now without success, I decided to do so again this morning. For reasons I don't fathom, running the deploy script after installing all the pre-reqs worked. Nothing changed during the pre-req install, everything worked as before, and the only potential issue was the version warning about hoek@5.0.4. Very weird, but at least it's deployed so I can start working with it.

Answer (score 0):

There was no real "fix" to my issue, other than to repeat all the pre-req installation steps a few times.